# 8 queens in Haskell, unknown error?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I'm trying to solve the 8 queens problem in Haskell without the use of any advanced functions, only with basic knowledge. I have come this far only but I'm getting an error that I can't understand.
The code:

```
queens = [[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] | x1<-[1..8], x2<-[1..8],
                          x3<-[1..8], x4<-[1..8], x5<-[1..8],
                          x6<-[1..8], x7<-[1..8], x8<-[1..8],
                          safeH [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1]
safeH xs e = if length xs == 1 then head xs 
                 else e /= safeH (tail xs) (head xs)
```

and the error message is:

```
y.hs:1:42:
    No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Bool)
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [1 .. 8]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x1 <- [1 .. 8]
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( y.hs, interpreted )
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: What type should `safeH` be? Currently there are two possibilities: `safeH :: [Int] -> Int -> Int` (`then`) or `safeH :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool` (`else`). Since you want to filter with `safeH` you want the last type to be a `Bool`. However,  in this case the right hand site of `e /= safeH (tail l) (head l)` is also `Bool`, thereby `e` should also be a `Bool`. It gets easier if you think of the types a little bit longer. Take your time to write the types, _then_ write the function.

Comment: It seems you are using safeH and expect a boolean return value, but instead you are returning the _number_ `head l`

Comment: I've changed `l` to `xs` in your code; this is more Haskell-ish, and `l` is sometimes less readable with certain fonts. :) (read `xs` as `x`, plural, like "axes").

Comment: It looks like you figured out your issue with the type-mismatch; it doesn't really work to edit your question and fix the original problem, because then nobody's answer makes any sense, so I reverted your last edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if ... then ... else ...` expression in `safeH` is not well-typed:

```
safeH l e = if length l == 1 then head l 
            else e /= safeH(tail l)(head l)
```

The `then` branch is incorrectly returning a numeric type, while the `else` branch is returning a boolean type `Bool`, as I think you intended.

You should add type signatures to all your top-level functions as a way of documenting what your code does, organizing your thoughts, and making errors easy to understand; the error message here is needlessly confusing because GHC infers that your code is returning some `Num` type thing from the first branch, and so when the second branch returns `Bool` GHC complains about the wrong thing: there being no instance of `Num` for the `Bool` type).

You should also read about [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) on lists, and take a look at the [implementation of `length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#length) and think about why it's not the best way to implement your function here.

So instead of using `length` and `head`, start with this framework:

```
safeH :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
safeH [n]    e = -- the case for a 1-length list
safeH (n:ns) e = -- ???
```

When you get something working then try redefining it where the base case is the empty list `[]`.

Comment: i have edited the code, can you please take another look at it :)

Answer (score 5):

The culprit is

```
                      .........
                      safeH [x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] x1]
safeH xs e = if length xs == 1 then head xs 
                 else e /= safeH (tail xs) (head xs)
```

specifically,

```
                 else e /= safeH (tail xs) (head xs)
```

because `e == x1`. So on the one hand `safeH` returns `Bool`, being used as a test in the list comprehension. OTOH you compare its result with `x1`. Which is `1`, among other things (`x1<-[1..8]`). I.e. `Num`<sup>1</sup>. Which must also be a `Bool`. Hence the error.

---

<sup>1</sup> A numeric literal such as `1` is parsed as a value of a polymorphic type `Num a => a`. I.e. its concrete type must belong to the `Num` type class. Since the concrete type is also determined to be `Bool` here, this means that `Bool` must belong to the `Num` type class, for this code to typecheck. Hence the `instance for (Num Bool)` is sought.

Comment: i have edited the code, can you please take another look at it :)

Comment: @YaserJaradeh no, no, you shouldn't change the code in question, because it might invalidate the answers. Your edit leaves the error in place though: you still compare `e` (which is `x1` in the test call inside the list comprehension, so Num) with the result of `safeH...` call which is still Bool, because result of `/=` is Bool.

Comment: @YaserJaradeh please don't edit your question anymore; try to fix your code and then ask a new question if you still must. :) More than 9 edits make the question "community wiki" and you won't get any reputation points for it. :) SO is a "question and answers" philosophy. Here the question wasn't "how do I write this code" but rather "why did I get that error?".